# Picture of the generators of fundamental group of genus g surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, fundamental-groups

It's a standard result that the fundamental group of a genus g surface has presentation

$$\pi_1(\Sigma_g)=\langle a_1,b_1 \ldots a_g,b_g | \prod_i [a_i,b_i] =1 \rangle.$$

Does anyone have a picture of say a genus 3 surface where these generating loops $a_i,b_i$ are explicitly drawn onto the surface?

For example I have see pictures like the one in this answer
[the fundamental group of a Riemann surface with n points removed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622864/the-fundamental-group-of-a-riemann-surface-with-n-points-removed)
or
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Fundamental-group-of-a-genus-3-surface_fig1_226810380
but those sets of 6 loops are different and it's not clear to me which one is correct for the above presentation, or which pairs are $a_1,b_1$ or $a_2,b_2$ or $a_3,b_3$.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That genus 3 picture does, indeed, give your presentation, up to an appropriate bijection $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\} \leftrightarrow \{a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,a_3,b_3\}$.

Comment: Mayyyybe [this picture](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVv0VWzbSEKA6CsuWqIvdcazn8ZJATKnDgOw&usqp=CAU) is a little more standard, but I don't know if the presentation is going to be any easier to read from it.

Comment: Thanks very much Lee, that picture is really helpful.

Comment: I've turned my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That genus 3 picture does, indeed, give your presentation, up to an appropriate bijection $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\} \leftrightarrow \{a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,a_3,b_3\}$.

Maybe [this picture](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVv0VWzbSEKA6CsuWqIvdcazn8ZJATKnDgOw&usqp=CAU) is a little more standard, but I don't know if the presentation is going to be any easier to read from it.

Answer (score 0):

Today have the same doubts as you. I found a picture in the book "Geometry and Imagination" by David Hilbert and Cohn-Vossen that illustrates how these generators of the surface of genus 3 works.
In second image, you will find beatifull pictures of pasting a decagon to get a 3-torus
[image: In one, you will find a description]

[image: In second image, you will find beatifull pictures of pasting a octogon to get a 3-torus]